# Column found in more than one table error

Tags: sql, hive

I'm getting the following error

> Error while compiling statement:
>   FAILED: SemanticException Column episodeid Found in more than one tables/subqueries [SQL State=42000, DB Errorcode=40000]

Would anyone be able to help me reconfigure?

Thanks!

This is the code in question:

```
select 
    papid, count(distinct episodeid) as epicount, 
    episovcountcesarean, sum(episovspendcesarean), 
    count(claimnumber) as claimcount, 
    sum(allowedamount) as spend
from
    3pdcoe_tc_dm_eoc_nep_peri.star_output_episodes e
join 
    3pdcoe_tc_dm_eoc_nep_peri.dbo_claimpatientservice cps on cps.episodeidd = e.episodeid
join 
    3pdcoe_tc_dm_eoc_nep_peri.star_output_aggregate a on a.episodeid = e.episodeid
where 
    aggtype = 'Window' and agggroup = 'Trigger'
    and eeany = 0 
    and year(episodeend) = '2016' 
    and episovcountcesarean = 1
group by 
    papid, episovcountcesarean, episovspendcesarean;
```

Comment: Qualify the column `episodeid` here: `count(distinct episodeid)` with the table, either `cps.episodeid` or `a.episodeid` or `e.episodeid`

Comment: Column episovspendcesarean needs to be removed from the group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

In your select list you must specify your target table

```
select 
  papid, count(distinct a.episodeid) as epicount, 
  episovcountcesarean, sum(episovspendcesarean), 
  count(claimnumber) as claimcount, 
  sum(allowedamount) as spend
```

OR

```
select 
  papid, count(distinct e.episodeid) as epicount, 
  episovcountcesarean, sum(episovspendcesarean), 
  count(claimnumber) as claimcount, 
  sum(allowedamount) as spend
```